# Polynomials for which roots can be expressed as polynomials in a single root

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

Classical Galois theory gives necessary and sufficient conditions for the roots of a polynomial in $k[x]$ to be expressible in terms of nested radicals of the coefficients.

Suppose instead that a single root $\alpha$ of $p(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is known. Are there known necessary and sufficient conditions on $p(x)$ such that all remaining roots can be expressed as polynomial (or rational) functions of $\alpha$ and the coefficients of $p(x)$?

For example, the cyclotomic polynomials have this property, since every primitive $n^{\textrm{th}}$ root of unity can be written as a power of some fixed root.

Comment: This is only possible when $\alpha$ generates the splitting field, which means that the Galois group $G=\operatorname{Gal}(p)$ has order equal to $d=\deg(p)$. Furthermore, since the action of $G$ on the roots of $p$ is also transitive, it must be the cyclic group of order $d$. Conversely, if $G$ is (cyclic) of order $d$, then every root of $p$ is expressible as a polynomial in $\alpha$.

Comment: The coefficients of $p$ are in $\mathbb{Q}$, so I guess you just want the roots to be polynomial functions in $\alpha$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$? Otherwise, can you clarify?

Comment: @RP_ The Galois group is not necessarily cyclic, if $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is any finite Galois extension then any $\alpha$ generating $K/\mathbb{Q}$ will work. We can also choose $\alpha$ so that its conjugates form a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $K$.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault To be clear, if $p(x) = a_{n}x^{2} + \ldots + a_{0}$ then I'd like an expression for the other roots as polynomial functions in the $a_{i}$ and $\alpha$ with coefficients in the base field. Of course, for a fixed $p(x)$ the other roots would just be polynomial in $\alpha$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @PadraigÓCatháin So you would like a universal expression valid for every $p(x)$? Then I don't understand your question as you ask for necessary and sufficient conditions on $p(x)$. The statement "All remaining roots can be expressed as polynomial functions (...)" is something that makes sense only after fixing $p(x)$.

Comment: Apologies for any imprecision - let us take $p(x)$ as fixed. The question is then under what conditions a root of $p(x)$ and its powers form a $\mathbb{Q}$-generating set for the splitting field.

Comment: It sounds like you want a condition when the polynomial is what is sometimes called Galois. In terms of what should the criterion be? For irreducible polynomials, the condition on the Galois group of the polynomial (viewed as a permutation group) is that it is regular.

Comment: @ArnoFehm Yes, for irreducible polynomials it is necessary that the Galois group be regular. But it is not clear to me that this is sufficient. The group need not be cyclic: the cyclotomic polynomials show that more-or-less arbitrary abelian Galois groups can occur for irreducible polynomials with this property. But the question holds also for general polynomials; $x^{n} - 1$ will have the property, for example.

Comment: @PadraigÓCatháin [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419172/polynomials-for-which-roots-can-be-expressed-as-polynomials-in-a-single-root?noredirect=1#comment1076405_419172) Thank you for clarifying. Then in your question, you should replace "functions of $\alpha$ and the coefficients of $p$" by "functions of $\alpha$".

Comment: Just a remark. This is related to how Galois himself did Galois theory from the point of view of the theory of symmetric function: looking at symmetric functions of all roots except one. See Theorem 6 in the paper "The fundamental theorem on symmetric polynomials: History's first whiff of Galois theory" by Blum-Smith and Coskey https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.4169/college.math.j.48.1.18

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $\alpha=\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, ..., $\alpha_n$ be the roots of $p(x)$. You want $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n) = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. If the Galois group is $G \subseteq S_n$, then $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1)$ corresponds to the stabilizer of $1$ in $G$, and $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n)$ corresponds to the trivial subgroup. So the condition is that the stabilizer of $1$ in $G$ is trivial.
In other words, the action of $G$ on the orbit of $\alpha_1$ should be regular.

All of this was basically said in comments above, but their seemed to be some confusion about the case where $p(x)$ has multiple factors, so here is an answer which doesn't assume that $p$ is irreducible.

---

As per discussion in comments, let $L/K$ be a Galois extension with Galois group $G$; put $N = |G|$. Let $\alpha \in L$ be an element with trivial stabilizer. Let $\beta$ be an other element of $L$. We want to write $\beta$ as a polynomial in $K(\alpha)$. Set $\gamma_j = \text{Tr}_{L/K}(\alpha^j \beta)$. Then the $\gamma_j$ are in $K$. If $K = \mathbb{Q}$ and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic integers, then the $\gamma_j$ are integers.

For any nonnegative integer $j$, we have
$$\text{Tr}_{L/K}(\alpha^j \beta) = \sum_{\sigma \in G} \sigma(\alpha)^j \sigma(\beta).$$
If, for some magic reason, we explicitly have floating point values for the $\sigma(\alpha)$ and $\sigma(\beta)$, and know the $G$-action on these values, we can use this formulato numerically compute the $\gamma_j$; if the $\gamma_j$ are then integers, we can round our computations to the nearest integer and get the result. In practice, I'm not sure how you'd get the $\gamma_j$, but I'll pretend you know them.

Let $A$ be the $N \times N$ matrix with entries $\sigma(\alpha)^j$ for $0 \leq j \leq N-1$. Let $\vec{b}$ be the vector with entries $\sigma(\beta)$ and let $\vec{c}$ be the vector with entries $\gamma_j$. So the displayed equation above states that $A \vec{b} = \vec{c}$, and thus $\vec{b} = A^{-1} \vec{c}$. In particular, $\beta$ is the dot product of the first row of $A^{-1}$ with $\vec{c}$.

The entries of $\vec{c}$ are in $K$, so it remains to show that the entries of the first row of $A^{-1}$ are in $K(\alpha)$. Let the Galois orbit of $\alpha$ be $\{ \alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_N \}$ with $\alpha = \alpha_1$. Then $A$ is a Vandermonde matrix in the $\alpha_i$'s, so the first row of its inverse is
$$\pm \frac{e_i(\alpha_2, \alpha_3, \ldots, \alpha_n)}{\prod_{j=2}^N (\alpha_1 - \alpha_j)}. \qquad (\ast)$$

Let $p(x)$ be the polynomial $f(x)/(x-\alpha_1) = \prod_{j=2}^N (x-\alpha_j)$. Then the coefficients of $p$ are clearly in $K(\alpha_1)$. The numerator $e_i(\alpha_2, \alpha_3, \ldots, \alpha_n)$ of $(\ast)$ is (up to sign) the coefficient of $x^{n-i-1}$ in $p$, and the denominator is $p(\alpha_1) = f'(\alpha_1)$. So $(\ast)$ is in $K(\alpha_1)$ and we are done.

My memory is that I read that this was Galois's proof, but I couldn't find the source quickly.

Comment: Yes! It is now clear to me that this is necessary and sufficient. Is it possible to describe the other roots explicitly as polynomials in $\alpha_{1}$ under these assumptions? (Which of course is what I should have asked in the first place.)

Comment: So, at this point, I want to know in what form the data is given to me. If you give me a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $N$, a subgroup $G$ of $S_N$ acting freely and transitively on the roots of $p$, another polynomial $q(x)$ and an action of $G$ on the roots of $q$, and you promise me that these actions extend to field automorphisms, I do know a way to get polynomial expressions for the roots of $q$ in terms of a root of $p$ from this data. But that is a pretty weird thing to promise me and not something you naturally get computationally.

Comment: I agree this is a weird set of demands, but in fact I think this is pretty close to my situation, actually. In any case, I'd like to see how it is done!

Comment: Regarding the history, I looked at the article "Galois for 21st century readers" by Edwards. He explains how Galois proved that (in modern language) each root of $p(x)$ can be expressed rationally in terms of a generator of the splitting field (Lemma 3 in his first memoir). The construction looks a bit different than the one from your answer, but apparently, Galois also uses the important fact that every symmetric function of the *other* roots $\alpha', \alpha'',\ldots$ of $p(x)$ can be expressed rationally in terms of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 15):

From a computational point of view, one should not try to compute the Galois group. Assuming $p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is irreducible, and $\alpha$ is a root of $p(x)$, it is sufficient to factor $p(x)$ over the number field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) = \mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x))$, and look whether all the irreducible factors have degree 1. In this way, you also get the expression of the roots in terms of $\alpha$. This is much less expensive than computing the Galois group, which is feasible only in relatively low degree.

Comment: I think this answer, and not mine, is the practical answer.

Comment: Yes! David's answer is wonderful, and I feel I learned something useful from it, but this is the way to get what I want computationally. Thank you both!